# Extracting a table from a text file using PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, multiline

I have a table that I want to extract from a batch of text file. The problem is that the table does not begin at the same line in the every text file. Also, the presentation, format, and reuse of keywords makes it really difficult to write a regex expression (for me at least). I've figured out how extract information from specific lines but this table is just a no go for me. I've researched regex expressions and splits but have come up empty.

The top of the file looks like this:

```
Summary Call Volume Statistics:

Total Calls = 1000
Total Hours = 486.7
Average Call Frequency = 2.05

Summary Reliability Statistics:

Total Queued Calls = 152
Total Calls = 1000
Total On Time Calls = 710
Total Reliability = 0.7100
Total Raw Demand = 640.00
Total Covered Demand = 437.79

Summary Business Statistics:

Total Servers = 4
Total Sim Time (secs) = 1752079
Total Server Time (secs) = 7008316
Total Server Busy Time (secs) = 0
Total Business = 0.0000

Detail Node Sim Reliability:

    Node       Calls     On Time     Percent      Queued     UnderTm      OverTm
--------    --------    --------    --------    --------    --------    --------
       0          97          81      0.8351          17     1637404           0
       1         115          92      0.8000          25     1637404           0
       2         103          90      0.8738          16     1637404           0
       3          68          53      0.7794          17     1637404           0
       4          63          57      0.9048           6     1637404           0
       5          35          29      0.8286           7     1637404           0
       6          31          27      0.8710           4     1637404           0
       7          40          36      0.9000           6     1637404           0
       8          22          17      0.7727           5     1637404           0
       9          26          24      0.9231           1     1637404           0
      10          24          21      0.8750           3     1637404           0
      11          23           0      0.0000           5     1637404           0
      12          23          20      0.8696           2     1637404           0
      13          15           0      0.0000           2     1637404           0
      14          20          19      0.9500           1     1637404           0
      15          19           0      0.0000           1     1637404           0
      16          23          18      0.7826           4     1637404           0
      17          12           9      0.7500           4     1637404           0
      18          10          10      1.0000           0     1637404           0
      19          11           0      0.0000           1     1637404           0
      20          13           0      0.0000           2     1637404           0
      21           9           7      0.7778           1     1637404           0
      22          11           9      0.8182           1     1637404           0
      23          11           0      0.0000           2     1637404           0
      24          14           6      0.4286           3     1637404           0
      25           6           6      1.0000           0     1637404           0
      26           6           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
      27           4           0      0.0000           1     1637404           0
      28           5           5      1.0000           0     1637404           0
      29          12          10      0.8333           1     1637404           0
      30          12          11      0.9167           1     1637404           0
      31           4           2      0.5000           2     1637404           0
      32           8           8      1.0000           0     1637404           0
      33           4           4      1.0000           0     1637404           0
      34           6           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
      35          11          10      0.9091           1     1637404           0
      36           7           0      0.0000           1     1637404           0
      37           5           0      0.0000           2     1637404           0
      38           5           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
      39           8           0      0.0000           2     1637404           0
      40           6           6      1.0000           0     1637404           0
      41           9           7      0.7778           2     1637404           0
      42           4           1      0.2500           1     1637404           0
      43           8           5      0.6250           1     1637404           0
      44           1           1      1.0000           0     1637404           0
      45           2           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
      46           5           4      0.8000           0     1637404           0
      47           6           5      0.8333           0     1637404           0
      48           3           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
      49           3           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
      50           2           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
      51           3           0      0.0000           1     1637404           0
      52           2           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
      53           3           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
      54           2           0      0.0000           0     1637404           0
--------    --------    --------    --------    --------    --------    --------
  Total:        1000         710      0.7100         152     1637404           0
```

Later in the file there is this table:

```
Comparable Node Alpha Reliability:

    Node     Raw Dem    Sim Rely     Wtd Cov
--------    --------    --------    --------
       0     71.0000      0.8351     59.2887
       1     62.0000      0.8000     49.6000
       2     56.0000      0.8738     48.9320
       3     39.0000      0.7794     30.3971
       4     35.0000      0.9048     31.6667
       5     21.0000      0.8286     17.4000
       6     20.0000      0.8710     17.4194
       7     19.0000      0.9000     17.1000
       8     17.0000      0.7727     13.1364
       9     17.0000      0.9231     15.6923
      10     16.0000      0.8750     14.0000
      11     15.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      12     14.0000      0.8696     12.1739
      13     12.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      14     12.0000      0.9500     11.4000
      15     11.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      16     10.0000      0.7826      7.8261
      17     10.0000      0.7500      7.5000
      18      9.0000      1.0000      9.0000
      19      9.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      20      9.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      21      8.0000      0.7778      6.2222
      22      8.0000      0.8182      6.5455
      23      8.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      24      8.0000      0.4286      3.4286
      25      7.0000      1.0000      7.0000
      26      6.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      27      6.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      28      6.0000      1.0000      6.0000
      29      6.0000      0.8333      5.0000
      30      6.0000      0.9167      5.5000
      31      5.0000      0.5000      2.5000
      32      5.0000      1.0000      5.0000
      33      5.0000      1.0000      5.0000
      34      5.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      35      5.0000      0.9091      4.5455
      36      5.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      37      4.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      38      4.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      39      4.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      40      4.0000      1.0000      4.0000
      41      4.0000      0.7778      3.1111
      42      4.0000      0.2500      1.0000
      43      4.0000      0.6250      2.5000
      44      3.0000      1.0000      3.0000
      45      3.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      46      3.0000      0.8000      2.4000
      47      3.0000      0.8333      2.5000
      48      3.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      49      3.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      50      3.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      51      2.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      52      2.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      53      2.0000      0.0000      0.0000
      54      2.0000      0.0000      0.0000
--------    --------    --------    --------
                          Total:    437.7852
```

I need to be able to store the two middle columns as an array in order to do some calculations.

How do I go about doing this in powershell? I already have the following code that works (with generic name changes):

```
foreach ($file in $files) {
    $fullName = [IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($file)
    $CR = $fullName.Split("CRAPTFV")[-2]
    $CT = $fullName.Split("CRAPTFV")[-3]
    $P  = $fullName.Split("CRAPTFV")[-4]
    $A  = $fullName.Split("CRAPTFV")[-5]
    $S  = $fullName.Split("CRAPTFV")[-6]
    $CV = $fullName.Split("CRAPTFV")[-7]

    $DEM = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern("Total Covered Demand = (\d*.?\d*)")

    $REL = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern("\d+\t+\s+(\d+\.{1}\d+)\t+\s+(\d\.{1}\d+)\t+\s+(\d+.{1}\d+)") -AllMatches

    Write-Output "$CT,$CR,$CV,$S,$A,$P,$DEM.Matches.groups[1]" | Out-File "fileadress" -Append
}
```

The goal is to use the table from each file to calculate some measurement and then append it to an output file. I seem to have yanked them out with $REL and I can see all the values with this code

```
$REL = Select-String -Path $file -Pattern("\d+\t+\s+(\d+\.{1}\d+)\t+\s+(\d\.{1}\d+)\t+\s+(\d+.{1}\d+)") -AllMatches
Write-Host $REL.Matches
```

But when I type the following I can only see the first value for each file. This

```
Write-Host $REL.Matches.Groups[1]
```

produces this:

```
71.0000
71.0000
71.0000
71.0000
71.0000
71.0000
```

for all files.

Comment: Not clear enought for me. First can you give a place to download an original file? Second can you explain what you want to extract from each file ? (there is no tab in the text you past inthe question, so your regex is not valid)

Comment: So, basically you want to extract the 2nd and 3rd column from the 4-column table in your second text snippet? Are there other tables with 4 columns in the files?

Answer (score 1):

If I imagine that 4 spaces give a tab here is a way to use `$REL` :

```
$REL.matches[0].Groups[2].Value gives 0.8351
$REL.matches[1].Groups[3].Value gives 49.6000
```

`$REL.matches[X].Groups[Y].Value` for a file gives the cell of th `Y` column of the `X` line. `X` and `Y` start from 0.